# How to resolve stored xss error on for loop static query

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have an issue regarding stored xss.I have also use JSENENCODE and `escapeHtml4()` whereever it was required.But still getting error on the following Code:

```
for(OpportunityStage stg : [select Id,APiName,defaultProbability,ForecastCategoryName,IsActive,MasterLabel,SortOrder from OpportunityStage where isActive = true  order by SortOrder ])
{
    lsttemp.add(String.escapeSingleQuotes(stg.APiName.escapeHtml4()));
    if(mapCategoryStages.containsKey(stg.ForecastCategoryName)) {
        lsttemp.addAll(mapCategoryStages.get(stg.ForecastCategoryName.escapeHtml4())));
    }
    mapCategoryStages.put(stg.ForecastCategoryName.escapeHtml4(),lsttemp); 
}
```

In the error List the error is showing on the First Line where we have use for    loop.Please provide me Workaround for this.

Comment: Can you add error message to your post? It will help to understand what is wrong here

Comment: @Khajiit The error I am getting is related to Stored XSS.As You can see in the code I have also used escapeHtml4() whereever it was required.BUtt still getting the error.